# iOS6/iOS 7 UIView transparency

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, ios7

So I have a game application, it has answer screen. Answer screen has 0.9 alpha and answer button has 1.0f. You can see on screenshot.

[image: iOS 6]

The same on iOS 7

[image: iOS 7]

Button alpha is still 1.0, but it looks transparent. If I do background view alpha 1.0 it works on iOS 7, but I extremely need user to see background under the view.

Please help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

for the view that is semi-transparent set the alpha this way:

```
UIView *view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.6];
```

not:

```
UIView *view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];    
view.alpha=.6;
```

Comment: Coolest! It works! Can you please explain what the difference and why this worked in iOS6, but not iOS7?

Comment: The difference is that you do not set the alpha for the whole view, you just set the alpha for the background color. Actually setting the view.alpha should have the same results in iOS 6 too because the button is a subview in the parent view. No idea why it worked in iOS 6 but it shouldn't.

Comment: @NikosM.: Hi... its not working for me. I have a view inside the main view. If I set the alpha of main view to 0.95 then the view inside it also get semi transparent. How to solve this? Please help.